# C# Regex to match all occurrences of a pattern and replace with empty string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a pattern `<two alpha chars>single space<two digits>single space<two digits>`and remove in all occurrences in a string.

```
var myRegex = @"(?:^|[\s]|[, ]|[.]|[\n]|[\t])([A-Za-z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2})($|[,]|[.]|[\s]|[\n]|[\t])";

string myString = "this 02 34, HU 23 76 , hh 76 745 1.HO 12 33. HO 34 56";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, myRegex);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                myString = myString.Replace(match.Value, "");
            }
```

In above variable myString "this 02 34" will not match as there is no `space or period or comma or new line or tab`. This is expected behavior.

But "**HO 34 56**" is not matching as it is not ending with `space or period or comma or new line or tab`. How can I include this in the match and not have a match for "**hh 76 745**"

After executing above code, I expect `myString` variable to have "**this 02 34,  , hh 76 745 1..** "

Comment: You could get rid of an awful lot of those square brackets.

Comment: @EdPlunkett when I tried with out square brackets like this (?:^|\s|, |.|\n|\t) it didnt work. But will double check

Comment: You know what `.` means right? Matches any character. If you want to match a literal `.`, escape it: `\.`. You really need to read some documentation before typing in random characters and hoping for the best.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes. only remove all matches of <two alpha chars>single space<two digits>single space<two digits> when it has leading or trailer with following space or period or comma or new line or tab or beginning of string or end of string

Comment: Here is one that follows this spec exactly - `(?<=^|[\s,.])[A-Za-z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}(?=$|[\s,.])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex with *word boundaries*:

```
\b[A-Za-z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5BA-Za-z%5D%7B2%7D%5Cs%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5Cs%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5Cb&i=this%2002%2034%2C%20HU%2023%2076%20%2C%20hh%2076%20745%201.HO%2012%2033.%20HO%2034%2056&r=)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]{2}` - 2 alpha
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[0-9]{2}`  - 2 digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

If you need to say "not preceded with alpha" replace the first `\b` with `(?<![a-zA-Z])` and if you want to say "not followed with digit" replace the last `\b` with `(?!\d)`. That is, use *lookarounds*, that, like word boundaries, are zero-width assertions.

If you really after matching that chunk *when it has leading or trailer with following space or period or comma or new line or tab or beginning of string or end of string*, use

```
(?<=^|[\s,.])[A-Za-z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}(?=$|[\s,.])
```

See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%7C%5B%5Cs%2C.%5D%29%5BA-Za-z%5D%7B2%7D%5Cs%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5Cs%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%28%3F%3D%24%7C%5B%5Cs%2C.%5D%29&i=this%2002%2034%2C%20HU%2023%2076%20%2C%20hh%2076%20745%201.HO%2012%2033.%20HO%2034%2056&r=)

Comment: Just to clarify `[\s,.]`: the `\s` already matches `\n` and `\t`, or even a regular space, there is no need adding them into the *character class*.